# Wordpress repository forbids me call wp-load.php in non-WordPress file

Tags: plugins, headers

I have made a Wordpress Plugin that is a kind of Download Manager. I have a external file download.php that is responsible for making downloads. This file is away of environment Wordpress, for this reason I must called:

```
$wp_root = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
require_once $wp_root.'/wp-load.php';
```

and I can use $wpdb for my sql query.

Note: This file must be external because I use functions "headers()" for force the download.

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: ".$ctype);
header("Content-Length: ".$size);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$info->url_file);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

My plugin works great!, But when I want to publish it on the Wordpress repository, they answered me that it is forbidden to directly call wp-load.php or wp-config.php

> Including wp-config.php and / or wp-load.php is not a good idea and we
>   cannot approve a plugin that does so unless it has a very good reason
>   to load the file(s). It is prone to failure since not all WordPress
>   installs have the exact same file structure.

I don't know that use for I can use $wpbd

This is my plugin -> http://demo.gopymes.pe/social-godownload/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Plugin approval team is more than right, this is not the way to do it.

First a couple of articles from a core developer and an excellent plugin developer, where you'll get to know **why not to use `wp-load.php`**:

- [Don’t include wp-load, please](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/), from Otto on WordPress
- [wp-load.php – I Will Find You!](http://crappycode.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/wp-load-php-i-will-find-you/), from Pippin'g blog *Crappy Code*.

When initiating your plugin, you can define the plugin's URL as follows:
`$plugin_url = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );`

And when calling your download script, you can pass the needed information in a query var, e.g., `$plugin_url . 'download.php?file=FILE-URL'` and `$_GET` it in your script.

This is just a general outline, more details on your plugin's logic would need to be provided if this outline is not enough. And, yes, as @AJHenderson points out, [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) is the place where you'll find lots of developers, including Otto and Pippin.

## Security notice

You need to have your download script tightly secured, as one could do the following:

```
http://example.com/path/to/plugin/download.php?file=http://example.com/wp-config.php
```